# Display output of numpy array on full length of screen

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pycharm, display

I want to display the output of a numpy array in PyCharm such that the output is printed on a single line. So I don't want that the output characters are split up into two lines as the example below. I want all the characters of the numpy array on the same line. Not like below:

```
[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0. 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.
0.  0.  0. -1.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0. -1.  1.  0.  0.  0. 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.
0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0. -1.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0. 0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.
0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.]
 [-1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0. 0.  0.  1.  0.  1.  0.
1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
```

How can I do this? What command, which setting?

[image]

Comment: This isn't a pycharm issue, but a display option in Numpy (& pandas). You can change these to fit your needs. Details in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am not mistaken, you can use this to increase the width of your display, for `Pandas` and `Numpy`. Do try these -

#### For Numpy

```
import numpy as np
np.set_printoptions(edgeitems=10, linewidth=400)
```

#### For Pandas

```
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('display.width', 400)
```

Comment: Thanks! The numpy command did the trick.